# Bipartite graphs coloring

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, coloring, bipartite-graphs

I was asked about an elementary (math olympiad) problem regarding members and committees, which can be formulated as the following graph-theoretic problem.

Given a bipartite graph $(V_1\cup V_2, E)$, where the degree of each vertex in $V_1$ is no less than 1 and the degree of each vertex in $V_2$ is no less than 2. We assume that for any two vertices $u,v\in V_2$, there is at least one vertex in $V_1$ which is connected to both $u$ and $v$.

Show that the vertices of $V_1$ can be colored in three colors R, G, B, such that each vertex in $V_2$ is connected with at least two colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the vertex $v \in V_2$ with minimal degree, such that no vertex in $V_2$ has adjacencies completely contained within $v$. Then, let $A = \{f : f \in V_1, f\text{ is adjacent to }v\}$, which is the set of all adjacent vertices to $v$ in $V_1$, and choose $g \in A$ to be colored red, while all other vertices in $A$ are colored blue. Then, color every other vertex in $V_1$ green. Since no vertex is contained completely within $v$, they should all have at least $1$ green vertex, and since every vertex in $V_2$ shares an adjacency with $v$, they also have one other color. Finally, $v$ has two colors since $g$ is red and the others are blue.

Comment: That's correct. Only the terminology is a bit unexpected.
So $A=N(v)$ is the set of neighbors of $v$. If $B\neq\varnothing$ is a proper subset of $A$, then $B$ is red, $A\setminus B$ is blue. Then $N(u)\not\subset B$ and $N(u)\not\subset(A\setminus B)$ for any other vertex $u\in V_2$ since $\deg(v)$ is minimum.